# URL not loading in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, basic-authentication, outlook-web-app

I am trying to get this Outlook Web Access demo account to load in an iPhone's `UIWebView`, and it does absolutely nothing. I don't even get an error code with the `UIWebViewDelegate` `didfailLoadwithError` method. Here's the details:

```
URL: https://webmail.123Together.com/exchange/  
Username: test@123Together.com  
Password: test
```

I would like to get this successfully loaded using `webView` `loadrequest` method if possible.

Comment: It doesn't load in a UIWebView.. It's just white screen.  Checking how it loads in a normal brower, I am thinking it has to do with the pop-up authentication box I am getting as opposed to the html login page that OWA generally uses to authenticate a user.

Comment: How did you solve this problem? Can you please share some links.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting and different approach is `ASIWebPageRequest` by Ben Copsey:

> The ASIWebPageRequest class included with ASIHTTPRequest lets you download complete webpages, including external resources like images and stylesheets.

Available at: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest

.. or, by the same author, `ProxyingUIWebView`:

> This project demonstrates a UIWebView that proxies nearly all HTTP requests via a local web-server.

Link: https://github.com/pokeb/ProxyingUIWebView

In both cases, you feed UIWebView with preprocessed html, so that it's not aware that this is protected content. Both techniques have limitations, and it's hard to say whether a web application as complex as OWA can properly work (in fact, it would be nice if you could report back your findings).

Note that `ASIWebPageRequest` is part of `ASIHTTPRequest`, a project that - as of this writing - has been abandoned. I am including it because *both* approaches are very interesting and worth studying.